# getProperties() returns different properties depending the $id sent to doctrine find($id)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

My code is:

```
$record = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Venues')->find($id); 
$reflect = new \ReflectionClass($record);
$props = $reflect->getProperties();
```

$props is an array containing 24 ReflectionProperty objects, related to the 24 properties of Venues class. That's the expected behavior.

My problem comes when I execute the same code and $id = 2, although $reflect object seems to be identical, now $props array will only contain 3 strange ReflectionProperty whose names are _entityPersister , _identifier and **isInitialized**;

I changed all the values on the record with the id 2 on the table venues in order to mirror other working properly. It didn't help.

I think that I'm missing something important but I have no idea what the hell it is. Please help ;)

PD:
I'm including the important code from:
Twig Array Extension:

```
public function arrayFilter($entity) {
    $fieldnames = $this->container->getFieldnames($entity);
    if (is_object($entity)) {
        $response = (array) $entity;
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($response as $k => $v) {

            unset($response[$k]);
                $new_key = $fieldnames[$i];
                $response[$new_key] = $v;
            $i++;
        }
        return $response;
    }
    return null;
}
```

that uses this function:

```
  public function getFieldnames($record) {

        $reflect = new \ReflectionClass($record);
        $props = $reflect->getProperties();
        $fieldnames = Array();
        foreach ($props as $prop) {
            $fieldnames[] = $prop->getName();
        }
        return $fieldnames;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing reflection on a Doctrine Proxy class. Doctrine uses proxies internally in order to provide eager hydratation and other features. This is transparent when doing a basic use of the entity you are working with, but if you use reflection or dump the variable you will see the all sorts of proxy properties and methods.

My suggestion, don't use reflection on a proxy, but if you really need so, tell doctrine to eagerly fetch your entities. Doing so will prevent the proxy mechanism from taking effect and polluting your entities.

Comment: Thanks, I need to read about the terms you are pointing to. As you suggest a different approach, I'll appreciate to to know which one you prefer for being able to retrieve the property names from a doctrine query result  sent to a twig view. My code above was a part of a twig extension that was reliable until I found this disconcerting case.

Comment: I'm sending a $record object to a generic twig view. This view uses  {% for key, value in entity|array%} for iterating this object and being able to display the key and value of any record. I have updated the code above to include the array twig filter code.

Comment: I finally solved the problem by following your advice and realizing that I should avoid the find($id) on my controller and use  $result = $query->getArrayResult(); on my repository, so this save me from using the Reflection feature.